# 303 response code not working (Stripe Connect with Angular.js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, ionic-framework, stripe-payments

What should I do with this code? As I understand it should redirect my request, but I only get an error.

**Error I get**

> :8100/#/stripeCallback? scope=read_write&code=ac_9JHtmTB7Y5cJQprWgaKPm1A6QLCbceQ8:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Here is angular http request I am making after getting user's stripe code. Now using this request I should verify it.

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: "https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token",
  headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
  },
  data: {
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    code: stripeCode,
    client_secret: "client_secret"
  }
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}, function (response) {
    console.log("Error -> ");
    console.log(response);
});
```

What is the problem here am I doing something wrong?

Comment: this needs to be done through a server. The whole point of a secret key is to keep it secret

Answer (score 1):

The [POST call to `https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token`](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/reference#post-token) must be made server-side as it uses your secret API key in the `client_secret` parameter. Your secret API key must never be shared with or embedded in a client-side application.